# No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer when compiling sass stylesheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, typeerror

I am having an issue loading my sass files in ROR. I did a clean install of my system and when running my application I receive the following when trying to link the stylesheet.

```
3   <head>
4     <%= render 'layouts/meta' %>
5     <%= render 'layouts/icons' %>
6     <%= render 'layouts/ie_html5' %>
7 
8     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "manifests/screen", media: "screen" %>
9     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "manifests/print",  media: "print" %>
10     <%= javascript_include_tag 'manifests/public' %>
11   </head>
```

Line 8:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

I get the same error when doing:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

I am not sure what I missed with my re-installation  of Ruby.

Ruby 2.0.0

'rails', '3.2.12'

'sass-rails', '~> 3.2'

EDIT:

This is my manifests/screen.scss file. The issue is that this application worked perfectly as is (and still does on production) but I started to get these errors after I reinstalled osx.

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-select';
@import 'select2';

@import 'global/colors';
@import 'global/fonts';
@import 'global/layout';
@import 'global/navbar';
@import 'global/login_form';
@import 'global/hero_unit';
@import 'global/basic_search';
@import 'global/map';
@import 'global/similar_properties';
@import 'global/eyecatcher';
@import 'global/footer';
@import 'global/property';
@import 'global/property_attributes';
@import 'global/pagination';


@import 'modals/share';

@import 'search/expand';
@import 'search/loader';
```

Comment: Sass does not usually provide error stack trace inside .sass files. You should check `manifests/screen` file yourself.

Comment: Hi Felix. Thanks for the suggestion. I added my screen.scss file to the post but as I mention the exact same code is running in production.

Comment: Hmm, it's not easily solvable problem, IMO you should comment all the lines inside that file and find the line which raises an error with uncommenting them one-by-one and checking if it stopped working. Maybe there was some change in the sass-rails gem or anything else.

Comment: Hi Felix. Sorry for the late reply. I commented out the entire content from screen.scss but the error is still thrown on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching I found a solution to my problem. I had virtus 0.5 and upgraded to virtus 1.0.4.